# How can I use qsub with Python from the command line?

Tags: python

I just tried this command:

```
qsub python commandLineDouble.py 1 10 1
```

and received this error:

> Unable to read script file because of error: error opening python: No such file or directory

I'm running this on a computing cluster that can usually `qsub` `.csh` files quite fine.

Comment: hum, did you try to run python alone? "error opening python" doesn't look nice here :-/

Comment: I think `qsub` is looking for a script named `python` to run in a shell.  I don't think that `qsub` will run arbitrary commands.

Comment: Running Python alone works totally fine on the original system. But I wonder if there has to be a separate instance of Python for qsub too?

Comment: Hmm maybe I could try a shell file that executes a command like "time python DoublePendulum.py 1 1 1"? I'm new to shell scripting though.

Comment: I'd just first `qsub` a script where the only command is `which python`, and take it from there (e.g. paths, other environment variables etc)

Comment: Hm - I just tried that. I also tried qsub on a "hello world" script. It didn't display anything though. Hmm.

Answer (score 7):

use -S option

`$ qsub -S $(which python) commandLineDouble.py 1 10 1`

Answer (score 6):

My impression is that `qsub` behaves differently from cluster to cluster.  However in my experience, I've always just done:

```
qsub myscrip.sh
```

Note that this is different than:

```
qsub bash myscript.sh
qsub csh myscript.csh
```

In other words, `qsub` is a wapper around a shell (usually a particular shell, but since shell's are similar enough, this isn't usually an issue), not around arbitrary commands.  The easy fix here is to just put your commands in a shell script and submit that:

```
#qsub directives here
#wrapper.sh
python commandLineDouble.py 1 10 1
```

Now you just do `qsub wrapper.sh` and Bob's your uncle (Assuming that your cluster's parallel environment has python installed...).

Comment: Wow - thanks so much! I have a class to go to now but I'll really try that out and see how that goes!

Comment: @InquilineKea I think this will work (at least this used to work in my qsub processes). Please accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Hmm - sadly - it doesn't work yet... Zhenya suggested a qsub on "which python" but that didn't display anything..

Comment: @InquilineKea -- Usually the environment which gets loaded in `qsub` is different than the environment you actually are working with.  In your login terminal (outside your `qsub` script), try `which python`.  You should get a path as you said that you can run the code outside of `qsub`.  Then copy that entire path into your `qsub` script.  e.g. if you see `/usr/local/bin/python` when you type `which python`, try putting `/usr/local/bin/python yourscript.py` into your qsub file.  If that still doesn't work, I'd suggest you contact the system administrators.  You might need `module load python`

Answer (score 1):

On PBS Pro you need to use a double hyphen if you want to supply an actual command line instead of a script:

qsub -- python commandLineDouble.py 1 10 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo "script.py  <args>" | qsub`?