# "Command not found" when using python for shell scripting

Tags: python, shell, sungridengine

I have this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print 'hi'
```

I'm trying to send this script as a job to be executed on a computing cluster. I'm sending it with `qsub` like this: `qsub myscript.py`

Before running it I executed the following:

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

However when I open the output file I find this:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

And when I open the error file I find this:

```
print: Command not found.
```

So what's wrong?!

Edit: I followed the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127722/syntax-for-submitting-a-qsub-job-without-an-actual-job-file)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `qsub` isn't reading your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line, so is simply executing your script using the shell.

This answer provides a few options on how to deal with this, depending on your system: [How can I use qsub with Python from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822344/how-can-i-use-qsub-with-python-from-the-command-line)

Comment: the idea is that I want to avoid writing bash script files

Answer (score 0):

An option is to set the interpreter to python like so:

```
qsub -S /usr/bin/python  myscript.py
```

I am quite sure there is an alternate way to do this without the `-S` option and have SGE execute the code based on interpreter in the shebang; however, this solution might be enough for you needs.

Also, concerning this output:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

It seems safe to ignore this:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/warning-no-access-to-tty-bad-file-descriptor-702671/

EDIT:

Also works:

```
qsub <<< "./myscript.py"
qsub <<< "python ./myscript.py"
```